# How can I best dynamically read all events from all topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am creating a consumer component (.NET) for my Kafka cluster. I have to dynamically read all events from all topics (even when new ones are created) and save them in a document based database. I have found a solution using the adminclient’s metadata and getting all topics every hour or so but I think there should be a better way to do this.
Does Confluent have something that covers this or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to modify the consumer properties to make the topic metadata refresh interval shorter, but yes, you can subscribe your consumer to a regex pattern of `.*` to read all topics, however, that'll also consume internal topics, so you may want to explicitly exclude those while processing records

Alternatively, Kafka Connect can use `topics.regex` for the same

Keep in mind that different topics may use different serialization formats, so your processing logic may not be the same amongst them all, so the above approaches can be very error prone. Therefore, may be best to enforce topic naming conventions like `json-<topic>` and consume only `json-.*`, then use JSON deserializer rather than constantly try-catch deserializer errors

Comment: This would basically be the same as I am doing now... I am looking for (if exists) a better solution. I was hoping Kafka has a method for this.

Comment: My answer is the only way Kafka has methods for this

Comment: I have used Kafka Connect with topics.regex to get all topics but my next problem is that this is not dynamic. So if new topics are created it will not subscribe to it.

Comment: The consumer API will periodically do a metadata refresh to find new topics. How long did you wait?

Comment: You are right, it worked